# Encountering Foreign Key Constraint Error When Deleting Rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, supabase

I have a PostgreSQL database with two tables, `types` and `order_items` where `order_items` has a foreign key constraint referencing the `types` table. When I attempt to delete a row from the `types` table, I encounter the following error:

> {"code":"23503","details":"Key is still referenced from table "order_items".","hint":null,"message":"update or delete on table "types" violates foreign key constraint "order_items_types_id_fkey" on table "order_items""}

Here are the table definitions:

**types Table:**

```
create table public.types (
  id uuid not null default uuid_generate_v4 (),
  name text not null,
  price numeric(10, 2) not null,
  user_id uuid not null,
  constraint types_pkey primary key (id),
  constraint types_user_id_fkey foreign key (user_id) references profiles (id)
) tablespace pg_default;
```

**order_items Table:**

```
create table public.order_items (
  order_items_id uuid not null default gen_random_uuid (),
  quantity numeric not null,
  order_id uuid not null,
  type_id uuid null,
  constraint order_items_pkey primary key (order_items_id),
  constraint order_items_order_id_fkey foreign key (order_id) references orders (order_id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
  constraint order_items_types_id_fkey foreign key (types_id) references types (id) on update restrict on delete restrict
) tablespace pg_default;
```

I understand that the error is due to existing references in the `order_items` table preventing the deletion of a row in the `types` table. How can I resolve this issue?

I've considered deleting referencing rows in the `order_items` table first or changing the foreign key constraint to use `on delete cascade`. Which approach is recommended, or is there a better solution that allows me to delete `types` while still maintaining related data in `order_items`?

Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sound like the database is performing exactly as it should. You have defined that order_items_types_id_fkey in public.order_items only can have values that exist in  public.types, and you are trying to delete one of those values from public.types, so the database complains. Either you remove the constraint, or change or delete the rows in public.order_items. I dpn't know your data, but it since the table is named order_items, I assume that it isn't a good idea to delete the rows. So change the type of the rows that still use the type, or if it is historical data, keep the type and mark it.

Comment: If you still want to leave related data in `order_items` you could change constraint to `on delete set NULL`. In this case you can delete entity from `types` and still have order, just without any reference